# Create Widget in SQL Notebooks

Tags: sql, azure-databricks

I am trying to use create widget in SQL Notebooks but it give me SQL Syntax error:

`CREATE WIDGET TEXT SSOT DEFAULT "2022";`

```
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'WIDGET'.(line 2, pos 7)

== SQL ==
--
CREATE WIDGET TEXT SSOT DEFAULT "2022"
```

Can anyone help me resolve above error?

Comment: Yes, it is on Azure Databricks

Comment: Are you running it on a cluster or on SQL Warehouse?

Comment: I get the same error with our SQL Warehouse, but not on my Cluster with DBR 14.1.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below ways to create widgets in SQL & python.

```
%sql
CREATE  WIDGET  TEXT text_filter DEFAULT  "2022"
```

[image]

[image]

You can also try the below approach using Python (work around):

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
text_filter = widgets.Text(value="2022", description="Filter:")
display(text_filter)
```

[image]

Know more about [Databricks Widgets In SQL Notebook](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/1395231203492935/2233887102570204/4227492383157538/latest.html)